# Why is my query returning 0 rows when running PHP, even though it returns 2 rows in SQLTools?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with two rows of filler information filled in at the moment. I want to pull some information for up to 10 rows of this database.

My PHP looks like this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT questionText, correctAnswer, wrongA, wrongB, wrongC, topic FROM quizquestions WHERE lang = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;"); //Pulls 10 random questions
$sql->bind_param("s", $lang);

$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();

if ($result === FALSE){
    echo("<html><body><h1> Error: Query unsuccessful </h1> <p>Arc Code are sorry for the inconvinience, please try again later  </p></body></html>");
    return 0;

}

if ($result -> num_rows <= 0){
    echo("<html><body><h1> Error: No questions found for that language </h1> <p>Arc Code are sorry for the inconvinience, please try again later </p></body></html>");
    return 0;
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo("success");
    //etc
}
```

Every time it runs I end up caught at the "No questions for that language" error, however when I run the query through SQLTools in VSCode I get the two rows of sample data I inputted.

For the example I'm running, $lang is equal to either J or P and is recieved from a html form. However changing it to a constant string, as I have to do in SQLTools doesn't change the output.

Comment: Luckily, we've got a complete walkthrough for solving this kind of problems

Comment: Most likely you are connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Or simply $lang doesn't contain what it should

Comment: @Dharman I'm not sure how it could connect to another one, I only have 1 mySQL database on my pc

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'll have a look at that walkthrough, thanks.
I did have an echo further up to make sure $lang was the correct character

Comment: `echo` won't show you everything. Use `var_dump` or set a breakpoint and check in the debugger

Comment: echo is not enough. it won't show you many invisible symbols, such as new lines. use urlencode() to have all special chars encoded and revealed

Comment: @Dharman Thanks you guys, the problem was $lang. It was showing as "J" when i echoed it, but var_vump showed it was null. I changed it to be a value passed into the function and it's working now.